# Hide ANR messages Android

Tags: android

I'm doing a streaming app and I really need to run this app with a foreground service... I have also to call prepare on a MediaPlayer object instead of prepareAsync because this case on some phone onPrepared event is not fired. This means that Android may show up an ANR message if streaming takes a long time, how can I hide this message? Is this possible?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how can I hide this message? Is this possible?

You cannot hide this message. Call `prepare()` on a background thread if `prepareAsync()` is giving you difficulty.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't... I have a foreground service to play a mediaplayer and I noticed some issue calling prepare in a background thread and then start in startForeground whitin the thread.. it doesn't work in that case.. :(